# $\pi_1$ of real Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

In the well-known classification of simple Lie algebras over the **complex** numbers $\mathbf{C}$, we have

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mathfrak{g}& \pi_1(G^{ad})=Z(G^{sc}) & \text{Example }G\text{ with }\text{Lie}G=\mathfrak{g} & \pi_1(G) & Z(G)\\ \hline
\mathfrak{a}_n\ (\mathfrak{sl}_n) & 1 & \text{SL}(n,\mathbf{C}) & 1 &  \mathbf{Z}/n\\ 
\mathfrak{b}_n\ (\mathfrak{so}_{2n+1}) &\mathbf{Z}/2  &\text{SO}(2n+1,\mathbf{C}) & \mathbf{Z}/2& 1\\ 
 \mathfrak{c}_n\ (\mathfrak{sp}_{2n})&\mathbf{Z}/2  & \text{Sp}(2n,\mathbf{C})&\mathbf{Z}/2& 1\\ 
\mathfrak{d}_n\ (\mathfrak{so}_{2n})& \mathbf{Z}/4\text{ if }n\text{ odd, else }\mathbf{Z}/2\times\mathbf{Z}/2&\text{SO}(2n,\mathbf{C}) & \mathbf{Z}/2&\mathbf{Z}/2 \\
\mathfrak{e}_6 &\mathbf{Z}/3&&\\
\mathfrak{e}_7 &\mathbf{Z}/2&&\\
\mathfrak{e}_8 &1&&\\
\mathfrak{f}_4 &1&&\\
\mathfrak{g}_2 &1&&\\\hline
\end{array}
and the algebraic groups $G$ with Lie algebra $G$ fit between the adjoint form $G^{ad}$ with trivial centre and $\pi_1$ maximal, and $G^{sc}$ with trivial $\pi_1$ and maximal centre.

Now, for each $\mathfrak{g}$ above there are finitely many real forms, i.e. Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}_0$ over $\mathbf{R}$ with $\mathfrak{g}_0\otimes_\mathbf{R}\mathbf{C}\simeq\mathfrak{g}$. My **question** is: what $Z(G^{sc})$ for each of these real forms, and what is the centre/$\pi_1$ for the standard examples like  $\text{SO}(p,q,\mathbf{R})$, $\text{SU}(p,q)$ and $\text{Sp}(p,q)$?

Comment: Splashing notation on the page like that makes your post pretty unreadable.

Comment: Thanks for that, has been edited.